# Images in ScrollView in android

Tags: java, android, scrollview

In my app I want to place a .png file and I want it to be viewed as a scrolled image at both landscape and portrait modes, please, suggest a code or example....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to scroll a container which contains an ImageView much bigger than the container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Container"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sky_bgr" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then use code to scroll it:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout container;   
    private int currentX;   
    private int currentY; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Container);
        container.scrollTo(220, 400);
    }

    @Override  
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
      switch (event.getAction()) { 
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { 
              currentX = (int) event.getRawX(); 
              currentY = (int) event.getRawY(); 
              break; 
          } 

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { 
              int x2 = (int) event.getRawX(); 
              int y2 = (int) event.getRawY(); 
              container.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2); 
              currentX = x2; 
              currentY = y2; 
              break; 
          }    
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { 
              break; 
          } 
      } 
        return true;  
    } 
}
```

Here many improvements can be made such as limit the scrolling range etc...
The other way is to control ImageView's matrix...
Then you can load an image into a bitmap and draw a portion of it on canvas etc

Answer (score 7):

To make your Imageview scroll if it doesn't fit in height, you can next a ImageView inside a ScrollView in the xml, & add this parameter -

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Here's an example -

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView>
<ImageView/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Good idea in theory but one scroll blocks another - you cannot sroll both x and y at the same time  on 2.2