# Scroll an Image horizontal and vertical

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked before, but I couldn't get an answer for my issue. I have a large image, and I would like to display it with it's full sizes (in fact its a custom map image). I know that the image can be scrolled by swiping the finger, but my question is if there is a way to implement a vertical / horizontal scrollview for this. I would like to be able to use the scrollview features (swiping the finger an the image is scrolling by itself). 
Using a HorizontalScrollView inside a ScrollView didn't work either. The horizontal scroll bar appears only sometimes, and there is no way you can scroll in both directions. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanls a lot,

Gratzi

Answer (score 0):

I've just answerd that question here [Images in ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990682/images-in-scrollview-in-android)

However it does not do scrolling by itself, that would need more programming.