# How to use ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView at the same time in a same View in Android

Tags: android, view, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am developing an application in which the user can take photos, and then each photo can be displayed in a **View** using its painted with the method **onDraw()**.

The problem is that as the captured image is high-resolution, does not fit the physical screen of the device, and only paint a part of it. For this reason, I want to give both the functionality of **ScrollView** as the **HorizontalScrollView** this **View** where it is shown that image, and can thus traverse the entire image without problems.

Anyone who could help me I appreciate it!!! 
Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990682/images-in-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, I think you would be better off using [the ImageViewTouch library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) which is published on GitHub under an MIT license. It lets you load a large bitmap with any zoom setting and then the user can use common gestures to pan/zoom it. Very easy to set up. I used it in several places in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need Two Way View, please check below link.

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view