# Redraw view on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have created on basic View which has Red color in background.I am using that view in my activity.I have setOnTouch listner to same view.
on touch events i am moving that view.

[Before touch event it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8fA1.png)

[After MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbGcu.png)

After motion event i want view to be redrawn.I don't want white portion to be shown.

it should redraw it like google map does on moving map in any direction.

following code is of my basic custom view

```
public class CustomVIew extends View {
    public CustomVIew(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

This is my OnTouch method implementation

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                _xDelta = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                _yDelta = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: X:" + _xDelta + " Y:" + _yDelta);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + _xDelta)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + _yDelta)
                        .setDuration(10)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: why you don't use `v.invalidate()` method to redraw?

Comment: @mehd azizi i tryed ivalidate on view which i get in ontouch method after animation,but its not working .It just draging whole view to new position,it is not redrawing like map

Answer (score 1):

you may need to invalidate the view .

this helps:
[When it's necessary to execute invalidate() on a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647558/when-its-necessary-to-execute-invalidate-on-a-view)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            _xDelta = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
            _yDelta = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: X:" + _xDelta + " Y:" + _yDelta);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             //do something like change the picture
            v.invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you change the background picture or somethings like that in ACTION_MOVE ?

Comment: no nothing I am changing its position only by animate

Comment: if you want to show a big picture and move around you have to add an image view in  scroll View . like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990682/images-in-scrollview-in-android